# Shiny selectInput only returning first value when multiple = TRUE

Tags: r, shiny, mapbox, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to create a map of bus routes with a selectInput that allows the user to select one or multiple routes that should then show up on the map (using mapbox). I've set the "multiple" parameter to TRUE so that the user can choose multiple routes. However, this is for some reason not translating to the map, where it is only showing the first route in the selection. For example, if the user selects routes A, B, and C, only route A is showing up on the map.

I added a text output to test if the entire input was being recorded, and it does appear to be. So, when the user inputs routes A, B, and C, the output text box does say "A B C", but the map still only shows route A.

Not sure where I've gone wrong, it seems to me that my filter command for the spatial dataset should work, so I'm not sure why this discrepancy is showing up. I've tried both with selectize = TRUE and FALSE, with the same issue.

My code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12,
      verbatimTextOutput("test"), #test text output to see what the inputted routes are
  
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(selectInput("routebox", "Filter by route: ", routes, multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE), width = 2),

        mainPanel = mainPanel(mapdeckOutput(
                      outputId = 'myMap'
                      , height = '500px'),
                      width = 10)
                   )
            )
          )
)


server <- function(input,output, session){
  output$myMap <- renderMapdeck({
    m
  })
  
  output$test<- renderText({ input$routebox })
   
  df_reactive <- reactive({
    route <- input$routebox
    
    #filter by selected routes
    return(
      data %>% filter(ROUTE_ID %in% route) 
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent({input$routebox},
    {mapdeck_update(map_id = 'myMap') %>%
        add_line(
          data = df_reactive()
          , layer_id = "arc_layer"
          , origin = "geometry.x"
          , destination = "geometry.y"
          , tooltip = "tooltip"
          , stroke_opacity = opacity_var
          , stroke_width = "thickness"
          , stroke_colour = color_var
          , palette = palette_var
          , update_view = FALSE
          )
      }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df_reactive <- reactive({
      data %>% filter(ROUTE_ID %in% input$routebox) 
})
```

or

```
df_reactive <- reactive({
   data[data$ROUTE_ID %in% input$routebox,] 
})
```

Comment: Ah this works, thank you - why is this though?